# Resolving bottleneck on database connection in Dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

We have a Dataflow streaming job that consumes messages in Pubsub, do some transformations, and perform DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on a CloudSQL Postgres instance. We observed that the bottleneck is in the database. The code is written in Python and uses SQLAlchemy as the library to interface with Postgres

Common issues we observed are:

1. It maxes out the allowed database connections, multiple connection pools are created.
2. When there is high-volume data coming in from Pubsub, the DoFn responsible for writing to the database throws these Exceptions:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending! task: <Task pending name='Task-194770'...
Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished name='Task-196602'...
```

```
RuntimeError: aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 429, message='Too Many Requests', url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/.../instances/db-csql:generateEphemeralCert') [while running 'write_data-ptransform-48']
```

Seems that the Cloud SQL API hits the rate limit here.

These should be our ideal scenario:

1. Regardless of the volume and the number of workers created by Dataflow, we should only have one ConnectionPool (a singleton) throughout the pipeline, with static number of connections (max of 50 allotted to the Dataflow job, out of 200 max connections configured in the database).
2. In moments of high-volume flow from Pubsub, there should be some mechanism to throttle the rate of incoming requests to the database. Or do not scale the number of workers for DoFn responsible for writing to the database.

Can you recommend of a way to accomplish this?

From my experience a single global connection pool is not possible because you cannot pass the connection object to workers (pickle/unpickle). Is this true?

Comment: Have you instantied the connection pool in the `setup` method of your `DoFn` ? It's the recommended way to create a connection pool per worker. Then the connections must be closed in the `teardown` method in the `DoFn` lifecycle.

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes, that's what we did. However, during moments of high volume of flowing data, to ease the backpressure Dataflow creates a lot of workers also in the write_to_db_dofn, so that it maxes out the allowed connections configured in the database itself. Is there a way to statically set in the pipeline the allowed number of workers on a specific step, say 2, so we can only have predictable number of maximum connections?

Comment: Since your question focuses on finding [set-up recommendations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394326/16929894) for your two requirements, the more appropriate forum to redirect your question to would be the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forums.

Comment: Hi @oikonomiyaki, did the answer resolved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to batch the call to your database. The pseudocode would look like this (taken from the [beam programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#batching-rpcs))

```
class BufferDoFn(DoFn):
  BUFFER = BagStateSpec('buffer', EventCoder())
  IS_TIMER_SET = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec('is_timer_set', BooleanCoder())
  OUTPUT = TimerSpec('output', TimeDomain.REAL_TIME)

  def process(self,
              buffer=DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER),
              is_timer_set=DoFn.StateParam(IS_TIMER_SET),
              timer=DoFn.TimerParam(OUTPUT)):
    buffer.add(element)
    if not is_timer_set.read():
      timer.set(Timestamp.now() + Duration(seconds=10))
      is_timer_set.write(True)

  @on_timer(OUTPUT)
  def output_callback(self,
                      buffer=DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER),
                      is_timer_set=DoFn.StateParam(IS_TIMER_SET)):
    send_rpc(list(buffer.read()))
    buffer.clear()
    is_timer_set.clear()
```

In principle, you would need to write a [splittable dofn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns) and use [timers and states](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers).